# Haskell infinite types and my FSM function

Tags: haskell, types

I've just come across the "infinite type" in Haskell when I was attempting to write a finite state machine. I thought the following was very intuitive:

```
fsm []     _     acc = Right acc
fsm (x:xs) state acc =
    case state acc x of
        Left err     -> Left err
        Right (s, a) -> fsm xs s a
```

I give the state function the current state (the accumulator) and the new event, and the state function produces the next state function along with the new accumulator. I recurse until I have no more events.

The compiler tells me:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t1 = b0 -> t0 -> Either a0 (t1, b0)
In the second argument of `fsm', namely `s'
```

Because `state` is now an infinite type. How to I rearrange this to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infinite types like this wreak havoc with the type system; they don't make it unsafe, but they cause a great deal of programs to type which you don't really want to, thus hiding errors, and I believe they make type inference harder too.

Thankfully, the solution is simple: you just need to make a `newtype` wrapper. `data` and `newtype` declarations are of course allowed to be recursive (otherwise, we couldn't even define lists!); it's just plain, unwrapped types which aren't.

```
newtype FSMState err acc ev =
    FSMState { stepFSM :: acc -> ev -> Either err (FSMState err acc ev, acc) }

fsm :: [ev] -> FSMState err acc ev -> acc -> Either err acc
fsm []     _     acc = Right acc
fsm (x:xs) state acc =
    case stepFSM state acc x of
        Left err     -> Left err
        Right (s, a) -> fsm xs s a
```

Comment: Thanks. To me, all this does is give the infinite type a name, but the type itself is still self-referencing. The compiler itself even named the infinite type the same way. I would've thought that the compiler would be able to automate this by giving it a name. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ana: While it is true that Haskell only deems your program invalid by *choice* and not necessity, it is for a very good reason; I don't have any links right now, but *many* common errors that we rely on the type system to check — like missing an argument or writing a function name twice — become validly-typed (but broken) programs if you permit infinite types.

Comment: Note that it isn't quite as simple as giving the type a name: `type Infinite = (Bool, Infinite)` is banned too; you have to wrap it in a *data type*, which sidesteps all the possibilities for errors, because you have to explicitly construct and pattern-match (or use accessor functions) on it.